# Strange Problem with Android, Program compiles but does not work

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, query-string

In my android project, I have a simple Java file which gets webpage content, does something with the text and returns text as a `String`. This text I display in a `ScrollView` in another activity on Android.

It works fine, but the problem comes when I try manipulating the text in this Java file. I tried with arrays, it didn't work then switched back to `String`, still nothing. It is just a particular method which fails to provide any output but the program compiles fine.

However, the same method when tried in a Java project in Eclipse works perfectly fine.

Here's my code:

```
// This method will return selected stripped text extracted from rawData
public static String FillMenus(String rawData){
    String resulT = "";
    int c1, c2;
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){ 
        c1 = rawData.indexOf("\" width=\"50px\" />") + 17;
        c2 = rawData.indexOf(" €</td>") + 2;

        if (c1==16 || c2==1) break;
        if (c1<=c2){
            resulT = resulT+"\n"+ rawData.substring(c1, c2); 
            rawData = rawData.substring(c2);
        }
        if (c1>c2){ 
            resulT = resulT+"\n"+StripTag((rawData.substring(0, c2))); 
            rawData = rawData.substring(c2);
        }
    } 
    return resulT;
}
```

If there is nothing wrong with this method, then why does it not provide any output? If I return `rawData` in Android, the phone displays everything properly. If I return the output result `String`, it is all blank in the phone.

If I call this method (say created in class `ABC`) in another test class (test.java) inside the same Android project say with `String a = ABC.FillMenus(String b)` there is something strange. I get a compiler error, while it shows blank in Android phone. And the same thing called from within a Java project works absolutely fine.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Show us what you're doing with the return value of this function

Comment: "Program compiles but does not work".  Welcome to programming ;)

Comment: "I get a compiler error" : could you specify what error? Might help, you know. I'm assuming also you made a typo and meant ABC.FillMenus(b). If not, there's your error. If yes, then have you imported the class if it's in another package?

Answer (score 1):

A few things

1) what is you for loop for ?

2) if (c1<=c2) and  if (c1>c2) are exclusive so I would recommend to change  if (c1>c2) to else (helps in the future when you want to change your code)

3) you should init result to null more than "", it will help you test at the exit of FillMenu to know when your code was skipped or when there is no values.

now my guess is that for some reason if (c1==16 || c2==1) break; is triggered and therefore resultT is never changed hence exists empty.

you should run this code in debug and put a break point in it, monitor particularly the values of c1 c2

a part form that I don't think there is enough info to help you more

Jason

Comment: Hi Jason, Actually i went through all the code again in Debug mode and found out that the loop is breaking on the first attemt at c2==1, and returns blank "".
However for the same text (String) input, it does not break in Java Compiler for some reason and works fine.

However, by further debugging i found out there is some character mismatch in android. The Phone does not read the "€" EURO symbol and shows it unknown. I tried to replace it with replace or replaceAll method but it just simply does not work, as android phone does not read this symbol returned from html page. What should i do??

Comment: Please have a look at the rawtext here:
http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/1692/problembj.jpg

My search string contains this text " €</td>" in which euro symbol shows something unknown in android emulator. I cant just figure it out how to change it, while this point is important ending characterset as i have to search the same in about 8-10 webpages on different locations.

Is there any workaround to change it to something recognizable in android. Problem is same character works fine in Java Compiler and it works well. But in android environment it just does not for some reason. Please help!

Comment: UPDATE:
I checked the webserver's encoding and it was ISO-8859-1.
I thought maybe it is different then the standard use be android, so i used the getBytes("ISO-8859-1") method to convert it back to standard.
here is the rawText response i am getting now:
http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/4310/problem2b.jpg

i have no idea, but i really believe this is the cause of problem. Do you have any input in this regard.

Comment: as you said you problem seems to come form the fact that the euro symbol isn't analysed as such in android. I've never played with the euro symbol but the character code should be "\u20AC" on the android. you should try playing around with that and "€". form what I checked "€" and "\u20AC" print out the same. so as far as detecting it it should be straight forwards. Displaying it I think you might need to need to add some bundle to your app maybe this will help http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ResourceBundle.html. In any case I think you should open and new thread for the € pb

Comment: UPDATE2: My appologies for writing too many messages here.
Although i have failed to find out a proper solution, here is a very cheap workaround that i have done:

 public static String Euro(String k1){ 
  // For example va?ue will replace unknown ? to € for further processing
  int k2;
  char test;
  for(int k=0; k<k1.length(); k++){
   test = k1.charAt(k);
   k2 = test;
   if (k2==26){
    k1 = k1.substring(0, k)+"€"+k1.substring(k+1);
   }
  }
   
  return k1;
 }


But meanwhile i'd be keen to know the proper way of doing it.
Regards,